# How to create a little database with search function and pdf download / upload

Tags: c++, database, file, file-upload, download

I'm trying to code a small program for my friend's company. They build metal cabinets and every cabinet is made out of several parts. So when a customer tells them they need a new cabinet, they tell them the single part numbers. My friend needs now a little tool/database where he can look after those part numbers and if there is an entry, he can download the corresponding blueprint (saved as PDF). Of course the program needs also a function to create a new entry and uploading a PDF file with this entry.

The program needs only to be installed local on one windows machine.

Now I need to know if there is maybe a special way to solve this. It would be helpful if someone could give me some keywords, so I can google it and figure out how to begin :)

I have basic skills in C++ and Java and willing to learn new stuff :)

thanks!

Comment: When words: little, friend, company and database end up together - beware! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have used sqlite for database applications and found it to have a lot of functionality and speed.  It lacks all the advanced database admin stuff but for single user/embedded databases its ideal.  I use it over MySQL because of a significant performance improvement.
It has a Java interface via java.sql.Connection.

Comment: many thanks to both of you! I'll evaluate both recommendations

Comment: sqlite is fantastic. I use it from c++ all the time for local storage.
I would imagine that the frontend might be a bit challenging to do in c++ unless you have an expensive IDE/compiler like Borland C++ Builder or MS Visual Studio that allows for some drag&dropping.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good opportunity to try something else than C++/Java. In your case I would go for Ruby on Rails and for example the PaperClip extension (http://thoughtbot.com/community/) (haven't used PaperClip myself, though). Ruby on Rails is kind of made for this type of problem.